# Grouped View - Show only one group

Tags: grouping

I have a grouped view on my hompage that displays the key milestones from each of our projects but it is becoming quite extensive.

What I would like to do is have a grouped view, where only the first project is expanded and users can then select to expand others as and when they want to.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you could do it.  You would configure your view to be completely collapsed, and by javascript (and jQuery), you would open only the first grouped node.